# Custom date/time based notifications

Tags: applications, notifications, push-notifications

Is there an Android app on the playstore that allows these features:

- Period notification reminders (daily, weekly, monthly, specific times, etc)
- Custom notification text
- Ability to send the same notification X times after the first reminder unless dismissed or the notification has not been swiped away (bonus)

I am looking for a way to set multiple notifications on my phone that at a specific time on a routine schedule. When the notification is fired it should read a customization text that I can set.

For example:

If I have a weekly reoccurring event called "Band Practice" that happens at 1PM on every Wednesday I would like a notification to be fired on that day once a week at that specific time with my customized notification text. As a bonus send that notification X times at an X interval until dismissed or number of times is reached.

Thanks!

Comment: Try Outlook calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally i use Simple Calendar that does all of your features. Altough the bonus, is if you snooze the alarm.
You can also set multiple alarms for one event.

Simple Calendar is ad-free.

Links:

- [F-droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.simplemobiletools.calendar/)
- [List item](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplemobiletools.calendar)

Comment: This answer deserves an upvote, plus I can personally vouch for the suggested app's reliability.

Comment: Thank you! I found a different application while searching called "Notify Me" which offers a more superficial customization (custom icons, notification colors, etc) at the cost of it being cumbersome to setup a reminder. The app you suggested makes setting reminders much easier as well as has a calendar to view reminders which is also very useful. If I had one improvement custom images attached to the notification would be nice. Thanks again!